# Altium Designer component search

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, eaglecad, eda

I am coming from Autodesk Eagle and I am new to Altium Designer. I just have a quick question. In Eagle I was able to have a lot of different libraries available in my library manager and whenever I entered something in the search bar, it searched for the component in all the available libraries. In Altium I added a couple of file base libraries to my component panel (.intlib and .dblib), some from the internet and one from me. When I use the search bar on top now, it seems to me that the search only happens in the library that I have currently selected. I tried it out with a couple of components.
I am aware that there is the manufacturer parts search that goes through Altiums cloud database and the file based search where I exactly have to define of the fields, but that is not what I mean.
Just wondering if there is a search that goes through all my file based libraries and that tries to match whatever I type.

Comment: You can get a lot of help on https://discord.me/altium - you need to create a login and join the server to take you to the celestial library where there is decent activity and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can search in all libs via the Components Panel.
[Altium Doku](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/integratedlibrary-pnl-componentscomponents-ad)